# Typing with enum fields concatenated with multiple random strings

Tags: typescript

```
export enum Test {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C'
  }
```

With this enum I can have a type that has A_2, B_2, C_2 fields with

```
 type TestExtended =  { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${P}_2`]: string };
```

What is the cleanest way to add other random strings ?
I did

```
 type TestExtended =  { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${P}_2`]: string } &  { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${P}_3`]: string } &  { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${P}_4`]: string };
```

So that I can have a type that has A_2, B_2, C_2, A_3, B_3, C_3, A_4, B_4, C_4
but with other strings the type starts to be very long any cleaner way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have `C_<any integer>`? What does "other random strings" mean?

Comment: No it is not an integer. It is something like p_ or _s     or  _p_e

Comment: Can you just do `type RandomString = "_s" | "_p_e"` and then `... as `${P}_${RandomString}...`?

Comment: Yes thanks this is the solution type TestExtended =  { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${RandomStringStart}${P}${RandomStringEnd}`]: string };

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Key Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) with [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) and [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). When using a Union Type in the interpolated position of a template literal type every possible combination will be computed. That newly generated Union is then [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to keys of the object.

```
export enum Test {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C",
}
type Suffix = "2" | "3" | "4";
type TestExtended = { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${P}_${Suffix}`]: string };
// type TestExtended = {
//     readonly A_3: string;
//     readonly A_4: string;
//     readonly A_2: string;
//     readonly B_3: string;
//     readonly B_4: string;
//     readonly B_2: string;
//     readonly C_3: string;
//     readonly C_4: string;
//     readonly C_2: string;
// }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCrAM7wN4BQccAgnALxwBEJVANEXAEIXVP2MDCrVnHAvgRgBPMMDgBlZADNpASxA8ATFTgAfagGZVGqgBYqAbiGjxWXAFEQMJABNgt1njgBtAApw5iOAGtgwiGk4ETFAzBx4AENsOAADABI8N34AfUSpWQV%20WIBdAC44XCgvAHM4fmMAekriOAA9AH4gA)

---

One last thing: You cannot define a type that contains *random* literal information because all types are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) at runtime.